# Why In This Case , Overriding Setter Method Is Not Working

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

sorry about title since i couldn't find a better one so any edit on that will be appreciated.

consider these classes :

```
public interface GlobalDashlet {        
    public Collection<? extends GlobalDashletSetting> getSettings();    
    public void setSettings(Collection<? extends GlobalDashletSetting> settings);

}

public class Dashlet implements GlobalDashlet { 
    private Collection<DashletSetting> settings;
    public Collection<DashletSetting> getSettings(){
        return settings;
    }
    //This Wont Work
    public void setSettings(Collection<DashletSetting> settings) {
        this.settings = settings;
    }

    //This Will Work
    public Collection<DashletSetting> getSettings(){
       return settings;
    }
}


public class DashletSetting implements GlobalDashletSetting {
}
```

Why overriding the setter method(i mean the way that i have done) wont work (the dashlet class complains about the unimplemented method) but overriding the getter method works?

how can i fix it? i need to be able to implement setter methods too (like the way that i have override the getter methods) because i have to serillize the Dashlet class with jackson mapper and Jackson can not determine the actual type of and object at run time without additional information on super classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that return types may be [covariant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_%28computer_science%29).

You can always return a more specific type (i.e. a subtype) when overriding a method. A more comprehensible example is the following:

```
class NumberProvider {
    Number getNumber() { return 1.23; }
}

class IntegerProvider extends NumberProvider {

    // Returning a more specific type when overriding:
    @Override
    Integer getNumber() { return 42; }
}
```

The type `Collection<DashletSetting>` is a proper subtype of `Collection<? extends GlobalDashletSetting>`. See the section about [Which super-subtype relationships exist among instantiations of generic types?](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TechnicalDetails.html#FAQ207) in the Generics FAQ.

For the setter, this does not work. The short reason why it does not work is: It is not type safe. An example of where the type safety is violated is easy to find, although it may seem a bit contrived at the first glance:

```
// This is the interface as it was defined:
public interface GlobalDashlet {        
    public void setSettings(Collection<? extends GlobalDashletSetting> settings);
}

public class Dashlet implements GlobalDashlet { 
    // Assume this was working: 
    public void setSettings(Collection<DashletSetting> settings) {

        // Then you could add a "DashletSetting" here:
        settings.add(new DashletSetting());
    }
}

// But someone who CALLED this method may not have given it
// a Collection<DashletSetting>, but maybe a collection
// like Collection<SpecialGlobalDashletSetting>:
Collection<SpecialGlobalDashletSetting> settings = ...;
GlobalDashlet dashlet = new Dashlet();

// Based on the method signature that was defined in the interface,
// this would be possible:
dashlet.setSettings(settings);

// Now, the "settings" collection WOULD contain a simple "DashletSetting",
// although it should only contain "SpecialGlobalDashletSetting" instances
// This would cause a ClassCastException sooner or later
```

The example may look a bit confusing. Again, it's more intuitive with the "simple" types like `Number` and `Integer`, but it boils down to the same problem: If a more specific type was allowed for the *setter* method, then the type safety may be violated.

Comment: thanks. although @Pranalee answered first but your answer is more complete

Answer (score 1):

Because it has different signatures.

`Collection<DashletSetting>` is not `Collection<? extends GlobalDashletSetting>`

you need to override the exact signature, not part of it.

if you have method that takes `Object`, you cant override it with method that takes `String` even the `String` extends `Object`

in youre case, `Collection<DashletSetting>` and `Collection<? extends GlobalDashletSetting>` are actually different classes, you have to override with the same class.

the getter is working since it has the same signature (same method name and no params), thats not the case in the setter

Comment: That doesn't explain why the override does work for the getter.

Comment: `you need to override the exact signature, not part of it.` doesnt explain it? because thats how java works

Comment: The OP clearly asked why it does work for the getter and not for the setter. "you need to override the exact signature" doesn't explain why you can override with a different return type. You can't override a method that returns Integer with a method that returns String. But you can override a method that returns `Collection<? extends DashletSetting>` with one that returns `Collection<DashletSetting>`. So why is that?

Comment: It's different for the getter and the setter because of covarience and contravarience.

Comment: its not different. they are both methods. java use method signature to override.

Answer (score 1):

Because overrided method can not restrict the scope of input variable. Original method can accept anything which extends `GlobalDashletSetting` class but, but overriden method isrestricting to only one subclass of `GlobalDashletSetting` class

Comment: how do you explain the behavior of getter method with this reasoning?

Comment: as of java 5 and above, `co-variant` return type of method is allowed while overriding